# MongoDB c# query subdocument

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb document, such as

```
"_id" : ObjectId("565e6c9b10bcd93ca8d1206c"),
"listHeader" : [ 
{
        "strName" : "MSID",
        "strVal" : "154800"
}, 
{
        "strName" : "Operation",
        "strVal" : "8221"
},
```

}

I want to query MSID =154800 and Operation =8221,

How to do in C#???
I had

```
var queryMod = Query.And(
Query<ModuleTestData>.EQ(e =>e.MSID , strSerialNumber),
Query<ModuleTestData>.EQ(e => "listHeader.Operation",      
             operation));
```

Not working? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regular expressions matching as below. The 'i' shows case insensitivity.

var collections = mongoDatabase.GetCollection("Abcd");

```
var queryA = Query.And(
         Query.Matches("strName", new BsonRegularExpression("MSID", "i")), 
         Query.Matches("strVal", new BsonRegularExpression("154800", "i")));

var queryB = Query.And(
       Query.Matches("strName", new BsonRegularExpression("Operation","i")),
       Query.Matches("strVal", new BsonRegularExpression("8221", "i")));

var getA = collections.Find(queryA);
var getB = collections.Find(queryB);
```